# Push an item in array using ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

```js
 class Demo extends React.Component{
    constructor (){
      super();
      this.state = {
        list : ['car','map', 'house']
      }
    }
    inputValue(e){
      var x  = e.target.value;
      console.log(x)

    }
 addValue(){
      this.state.list.push();
      this.setState({list: this.state.list});
    }
 render(){
   return(
   <div>
    <input onChange={this.inputValue} type="text"/>
        <ul>
          {this.state.list.map(item => (
            <li>{item}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
    <button onClick={this.addValue.bind(this)}>Add Element</button>
   </div>
   )
 }
  }
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Demo/>,
    document.getElementById('test')
  )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Using my code, how can i push the value from `<input onChange={this.inputValue} type="text"/>` in `list : ['car','map', 'house']`. I use for this `addValue` function, but i can't insert the x variable from `inputValue` function  in `push()` from `addValue` function. How to do this using my code?

Comment: Hi Asking, please try my solution below and let me know if that helps :)

Comment: Thats great to hear. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `state` value for the text-input so that your `addValue()` function knows what to use when its time to add a new item. The text `state` will be updated with anything the user types.

Working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-feynman-fze1n

```
import React from "react";

class Demo extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      text: "",
      list: ["car", "map", "house"]
    };
  }
  inputValue(e) {
    this.setState({
      text: e.target.value
    });
  }
  addValue() {
    const text = this.state.text;
    this.setState({ list: [...this.state.list, text] });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input onChange={this.inputValue.bind(this)} type="text" />
        <ul>
          {this.state.list.map(item => (
            <li>{item}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
        <button onClick={this.addValue.bind(this)}>Add Element</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Demo;
```

Also, refrain from doing direct state-mutations like `this.state.list.push(blah)`. This is against React principles and can lead to unwanted visual side-effects. If you need to reference an existing `state`, try to create a copy of it instead. In the case for you list, we use the spread-operator to create a shallow-copy and then added the new item to the array..

Answer (score 0):

Since React is all about small components and reusability consider breaking it up into two separate components... That way, if you need a form anywhere else you can reuse it...

Here is your Demo:

```
class Demo extends Component {
    state = { list: ['car', 'map', 'house'] };

    addItem = item => {
        this.setState({ list: [item, ...this.state.list] });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Form addItem={this.addItem} />
                {this.state.list.map((item, index) => (
                    <div key={index}>{item}</div>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And here is the Form:

```
class Form extends Component {
    state = { item: '' };

    handleChange = event => {
        this.setState({ item: event.target.value });
    };

    handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.addItem(this.state.item);
        this.setState({ item: '' });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input
                    type='text'
                    value={this.state.item}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

Live Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-611uzp